# Unable to Save images to database

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, python-imaging-library, filefield

am unable to save images containing url on database this will give me an error

> if file and not file._committed:
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_committed'

this error is as a result of my attempts to save this scraped image with beautiful soup

below are images list that refused to be saved on my models , this images are been scraped with beautiful soup

something like this brought the images

```
images = [i['data-src'] for i in soup.find_all('img', {'class','attachment-jnews-750x375 size-jnews-750x375 lazyload wp-post-image'})]
```

https://people.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/ad1-746x375.jpg
https://people.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/caroon-1-600x375.jpg

why this code brought the above error

```
Post.objects.create(
                title=title,
                content_1=paragraphs,
                image=images,
                sources=lnk,
            )
```

this is my model.py example code

```
         class Post(models.Model):
               title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank = True, help_text='Maximum 160 Title characters.')
               image = models.FileField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True,  help_text='You must upload original image before continuing.')
```

but i get this error

> if file and not file._committed: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_committed'

but if am saving normal jpeg file it is always a success.

how do i save this scraped images to models

Comment: The error seems pretty clear.  You are passing a LIST of images to an API that expects a single image.  If you have multiple images, then you will need to use a loop like `for image in images:` / `Post.objects.create(...)`.  And by the way, the word is "scraped", not "scrapped".  "Scrapped" means "trashed".

Comment: @TimRoberts please you could have just shown me an example, please show me ways to resolve this mess

Comment: what Tim says you can solve it by using forloop.

Comment: I gave you the reasons and the fix.  Replace `Post.objects.create( ... image=images ... )` with `for image in images:` / `Post.objects.create( ... image=image ... )`.

Comment: Tanks for your quick reply dear @TimRoberts  but i still got an error on the /    inde image in images: / Post.objects.create(
                    title=title,
                    content_1=content,
                    image=images,
                    sources=lnk,
                )

Comment: File "<console>", line 11
    for image in images: / Post.objects.create(
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax at /

Comment: Sir @SerioUs an error was obtained trying to execute your code sir. please help   File "<console>", line 11
    for image in images: / Post.objects.create(
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @TimRoberts when the slash / is remove it throughs an exception  or error that     if file and not file._committed:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_committed'